# Angular $rootScope Properties undefined after Asynchronous API

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, scope, rootscope

I have main controller:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Data', '$http', '$log', '$filter', '$q', '$timeout', function($scope, $rootScope, Data, $http, $log, $filter, $q, $timeout){

            Data.get('customers').then(function(data){
                $scope.customers = data.data;
                $rootScope.language = data.data[0].language;
            });

            $rootScope.word_pub_curr_lang = 'word_pub_' + $rootScope.language;
            console.log('from maincrtl', $rootScope.word_pub_curr_lang);

    }]);
```

The problem is that I can't receive $rootScope.word_pub_curr_lang or $rootScope.language - are always undefined.

Answer (score 3):

It is getting undefined because, it gets printed before you actually get the value from the request, place them inside,

```
controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'Data', '$http', '$log', '$filter', '$q', '$timeout', function($scope, $rootScope, Data, $http, $log, $filter, $q, $timeout){
            Data.get('customers').then(function(data){
                $scope.customers = data.data;
                $rootScope.language = data.data[0].language;
                $rootScope.word_pub_curr_lang = 'word_pub_' + $rootScope.language;
               console.log('from maincrtl', $rootScope.word_pub_curr_lang);
            });

    }]);
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to have it accessible everywhere, in other controller, view...

Comment: @andrzej after getting the result, you can access it from anywhere